# zgrep not stop the script like grep do

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix

I'm new to Bash script and I'm trying to make this script to do read line by line of file a.txt.gz and check if that second value of the line is existed in b.txt.gz file too

I don't know why the zgrep won't end the script, after read a.txt.gz it stuck at the flashed pointer

here is the code (test)

```
zcat /home/tdq/Bash/a.txt.gz | while read p0 p1
do
if zgrep -q -e "[A-Za-z0-9=;._|()\t]*${p1}[A-Za-z0-9=;._|()\t]*" /home/tdq/Bash/b.txt.gz; then
    echo "FOUND"
fi
```

The result as I run `time ./test` is as I expected but the script won't end, here is the output

```
FOUND
FOUND
FOUND
```

I tried to use grep, not a `FOUND` but it can end the script.

```
zcat /home/tdq/Bash/a.txt.gz | while read p0 p1
do
    if grep -q -e "[A-Za-z0-9=;._|()\t]*${p1}[A-Za-z0-9=;._|()\t]*" /home/tdq/Bash/b.txt.gz; then
        echo "FOUND"
    fi
done
```

The result as I run `time ./test`

```
real    0m9.361s
user    0m6.660s
sys 0m2.196s
tdq@td:~/bash$
```

Can someone help me out, many thanks

a.txt.gz (tab seperate)

```
1   rs367896724
2   rs540431307
3   rs555500075
4   rs548419688
```

b.txt.gz (tab seperate)

```
1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  100 PASS    AC=2130;AF=0.425319;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=103152;EAS_AF=0.3363;AMR_AF=0.3602;AFR_AF=0.4909;EUR_AF=0.4056;SAS_AF=0.4949;AA=|||unknown(NO_COVERAGE);VT=INDEL GT  1|0 0|1 0|1
2   10177   rs540431307 A   AC  100 PASS    AC=2130;AF=0.425319;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=103152;EAS_AF=0.3363;AMR_AF=0.3602;AFR_AF=0.4909;EUR_AF=0.4056;SAS_AF=0.4949;AA=|||unknown(NO_COVERAGE);VT=INDEL GT  1|0 0|1 0|1
3   10177   rs555500075 A   AC  100 PASS    AC=2130;AF=0.425319;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=103152;EAS_AF=0.3363;AMR_AF=0.3602;AFR_AF=0.4909;EUR_AF=0.4056;SAS_AF=0.4949;AA=|||unknown(NO_COVERAGE);VT=INDEL GT  1|0 0|1 0|1
4   10177   rs548419688 A   AC  100 PASS    AC=2130;AF=0.425319;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=103152;EAS_AF=0.3363;AMR_AF=0.3602;AFR_AF=0.4909;EUR_AF=0.4056;SAS_AF=0.4949;AA=|||unknown(NO_COVERAGE);VT=INDEL GT  1|0 0|1 0|1
```

Basically,  I have to check for rsxxxxx match each other in a.txt.gz and b.txt.gz

---

c.txt.gz

```
10084625    rs123
10026407    rs456
```

d.txt.gz (this is original file)

```
514786698   10084625    491891820   4   12951   0.986   562 421
5221808     495944      1573768     4   664     0.261062   59   2
539535670   10026407    556933170   3   \N  \N  \N  \N
```

output file (c.txt.gz + d.txt.gz = e.txt.gz)

```
514786698   10084625    491891820   4   12951   0.986   562 421
5221808 \N  \N  \N  \N
539535670   10026407    556933170   3   \N  \N  \N  \N
```

Expected output file (c.txt.gz + d.txt.gz = e.txt.gz)

```
514786698   10084625    491891820   4   12951   0.986   562 421
539535670   10026407    556933170   3   \N  \N  \N  \N
```

So it wrote down the line in d.txt.gz that not in the c.txt.gz (second line - 495944)

Comment: *after read a.txt.gz it stuck at the flashed pointer* How do you know it's stuck and isn't still running?

Comment: To debug shell scripts, put `set -x` at the beginning. It will show you the lines as it's executing them, then you can see what it's doing.

Comment: `grep` is much faster because it doesn't have to expand the file every time you call it.

Comment: BTW, there's no point in ending the pattern with `[...]*`. Since that matches zero repetitions of the character class, it doesn't add anything to the search.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I tested on small file (117 bytes) and I waited for 30m, all line of the a.txt.gz file have printed on my terminal, but the script not exit

Comment: There also doesn't seem to be any point to the `[...]*` at the beginning. You should just be able to do `zgrep -q "$p1" /home/tdq/Bash/b.txt.gz`

Comment: Please post some sample data from `a.txt`, `b.txt` and expected output.

Comment: @Barmar I need to search on a gz file. I googled it they said I should use zgrep. Any change I can use grep to seach in a gz file

Comment: You can't use `grep` to search a gz file. I was just explaining why that will be much faster, but it won't give the correct result.

Comment: @JamesBrown Please view my edit

Answer (score 1):

Using awk and process substitution:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}($3 in a){print "FOUND"}' <(zcat a.txt.gz ) <(zcat b.txt.gz)
FOUND
FOUND
FOUND
FOUND

awk '
NR==FNR {                            # first file hash to a on second field
    a[$2]
    next }                           # next record
($3 in a){                           # second file
    print "FOUND" }                  # print FOUND when found (more informative?)
' <(zcat a.txt.gz ) <(zcat b.txt.gz) # uncompress and use process substitution
```

For your edited data and expected output:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }          # hash the first file, use $1 field as key
($2 in a)                       # second file, if $2 field value is found in a, 
                                # ($2 in a) evaluates to true 
                                # which initiates implicit printing of the record
' <(zcat c.txt.gz ) <(zcat d.txt.gz)

514786698   10084625    491891820   4   12951   0.986   562 421
539535670   10026407    556933170   3   \N  \N  \N  \N
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if the b.txt.gz is small, but now I notice that when the b.txt.gz becomes large (~1G), this still stuck at the flashed pointer. It seems like the script keep reading all lines of the b.txt.gz file.

Comment: I tried this out and it took real 5m11.387s
user 9m37.188s
sys 0m18.260s

Comment: It does. It uncompresses `a.txt.gz` and hashes it to memory. Then uncompresses `b.txt.gz` and goes thru every record comparing it to the hash `a` in memory. Was there an exit rule I missed in the OP?

Comment: Thank for your help, but I notice when using awk they wrote the data down to a output file wrong. Just some lines are wrong data, like it didn't break the line correctly! Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't understand that at all. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Are you saying that above presented `a.txt.gz` and `b.txt.gz` should somehow produce that output?

Comment: Yes! please, but that just another file data. But the logic is the same

Comment: I cannot imagine the source files. Post them and respective expected output.

Comment: Added another version.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, which command do you recommend for fasted loop a large gz file (> 1G), gunzip? while read ? awk ?

Comment: Last time I used bash `while` I was given this: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) so I'd say decompress first, then awk.